# How to set different colours for one object according to a variable in flask and html?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have a website written in python(flask) and html with objects which I want to set in  different colours. The objects are places which can be reserved, so I want when a place is available to be in green, when is reserved in red, the status of the place is in the python code. And this to be visible after a refresh of the page. I have searched but nothing works for me. If someone know how to do it?

Comment: The HTML should be a jinja template. You should use `render_template` and pass the proper colors based on your inner logic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="other-styles {{'available' if place == 'available' }}">
```

in style

```
.available {
 background-color: green;
}
```